# updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I am getting this error while switching to the last fragment of the bottom navigation and because of this the last fragment loads a little bit slow

`E/FrameEvents: updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame. 2022-01-03 12:35:41.373 14186-15042/com.pandojo E/BufferQueueProducer: [ImageReader-329x48f1u256m2-14186-447](id:376a000001bf,api:0,p:-1,c:14186) disconnect: not connected (req=1) 2022-01-03 12:35:41.373 14186-15042/com.pandojo W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7b81c7d010 disconnect failed`

Comment: In my case it's not an error but a [short] warning -> ```E/FrameEvents(28112): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.``` <- but like you I have no idea what is causing this warning. I am coding in Dart-Flutter (IDE: VSCodium).